How to Integrate Pulumi with OpenAPI Spec for AWS API Gateway and Lambda Without Redundant Endpoint Declarations?
I am using Pulumi to provision a REST API with AWS API Gateway and Lambda integrations. Currently, I maintain a manually written OpenAPI spec (we follow a spec-first approach) and Pulumi code to provision all API endpoints, their Lambda integrations, and the Lambdas themselves. This means I manually define all endpoints in both the specification and the Pulumi code. I want to streamline this by using the OpenAPI spec directly for Pulumi generation.
To use the spec as a source for Pulumi, I need to extend it with AWS API Gateway-specific information, e.g.,
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
  "uri": "[lambda-arn]",
  "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
  "httpMethod": "POST",

For the Lambda integration, I need to specify the Lambda ARN, but since the Lambdas are also Pulumi-managed resources, I can't hardcode the ARN in the spec.
How can I avoid declaring all endpoints in both Pulumi and OpenAPI? Is there a best practice for this?
